# Do I need the comma in "it is in short...everthing"?

Tags: grammar, commas, parentheticals, editing

The intended meaning is that 'it', described simply, is 'everything'.

Would I write:

> It is in short...everything.

Or:

> It is, in short...everthing.

Instinctively, I believe that a comma is needed before "in short".

But the confusion arises here:

Is it a common enough phrase that the comma is not needed? Is it a publisher's preference situation? Author's preference? I've seen the phrase 'in short' both with and without commas. Normally two commas are used, as it's a parenthetical, but the ellipsis makes the second one unnecessary.

Comment: Common?  I have no idea what it means.

Comment: I agree, the comma followed by an ellipsis is a strange encounter.   Why not just opt for the commas and ditch the ellipsis?  It is, in short, everything.

Comment: What is the sentence intended to mean?

Comment: Is this dialog/speech — where the ellipsis indicates a wait-for-it punchline? If not, try: *It is, in short, everything.*

Comment: But *in short* makes it longer…

Comment: It is much easier to understand with the comma. Use it.

Comment: For everyone asking, "it is everything" is just a modish way of saying something is really great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which (if any) is the grammatically correct form of this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583241/which-if-any-is-the-grammatically-correct-form-of-this-sentence) Short parentheticals are not barred from taking zero offsetting punctuation; the introductory comma (before 'in') is a style choice here. Do you want to cue for a short pause? I would do. // The end punctuation (after 'short') being different is unusual, but I'd agree warranted here. Punctuation is here to serve; unusual choices should be avoided where they might confuse, but ...

Comment: otherwise chosen purely so as to best reflect the spoken word as intended. Here, I'd want the short pause (signalled by a comma) then the long one (a dash or ellipsis). // See also [Is _in fact_ always set off by commas mid-sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154464/is-in-fact-always-set-off-by-commas-mid-sentence) for analysis of offsetting punctuation around short  and especially fixed-phrase parentheticals.

Answer (score 0):

It's such a clumsy sentence - more pauses than actual words. I'd opt for "In short it is everything." and ditch all the fussy extras, but that's just me. I learned to write for newspapers so I always look for a short, sharp sentence structure where possible. Best of luck!

Comment: Hello, Gristle. Possibly sound advice, but as it doesn't directly answer the actual question, more suitable as a 'comment'.